# How to get id of clicked element in highchart contextmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Is there any way to get the id of clicked button on highchart context menu Or any way to trigger the click function two times?

```
  contextButtonArray = [];
  contextButtonArray.push({
      {
        text: 'TEST BUTTON',
        onclick: function) {
        console.log("HELLO");


      }
      contextButton: {
        // 800px by default, PNG by default
        menuItems: contextButtonArray
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **wrap** the `onclick` event of every context menu button:

```
(function(H) {
  var menuItems = H.defaultOptions.exporting.menuItemDefinitions;
  for (var prop in menuItems) {

    var item = menuItems[prop];
    if (!item.separator) {

      H.wrap(item, 'onclick', function(proceed, event) {
        console.log(event.target.innerText + ' button clicked!');
        proceed.call(this);
      });

    }
  };
})(Highcharts);
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j46w9sLr/

`proceed` is the function that originally fired on button click. You can call it multiple times just by adding another `proceed.call(this);` line. `event` argument can be used to retrieve the information about which button was clicked.

**Doc about wrapping:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts